# How to retrieve taxonomy term friendly URL or simple URL?

Tags: taxonomy

I am creating a menu control that read terms from taxonomy term store. Get termSet and term is straight forward

```
        using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(siteCollecitonUrl))
        {
            TaxonomySession taxSession = new TaxonomySession(siteCollection);
            TermStore taxStore = taxSession.TermStores[0];
            Group taxGroup = taxStore.GetSiteCollectionGroup(siteCollection);
            TermSet termSet = taxGroup.TermSets[strTermSetsName];

            foreach (term in termSet.terms)
            {
                term.???
            }
        }
```

but how to retrieve friendly URL or simple url link?

I could not find a property or method.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, after your export the URL into a CSV, how do you import it back?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to use NavigationTerm

To Create Term set:

```
  NavigationTerm term2 = navTermSet.CreateTerm("Term 2", NavigationLinkType.FriendlyUrl,
                    term2Guid);
```

/// Verify that the NavigationTermSetView is being applied correctly.

```
 Assert.AreEqual(web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/term-2", term2.GetResolvedDisplayUrl(null).ToString());
```

In order to add new terms to navigation term set, you can use the following code:

```
// Obtain navigation term set
NavigationTermSet navigationTermSet = NavigationTermSet.GetAsResolvedByWeb(termSet, web, "GlobalNavigationTaxonomyProvider");
// Specify that this term set can be used for site navigation
navigationTermSet.IsNavigationTermSet = true;
// Creates new term pointing to an already existing URL outside of SharePoint
NavigationTerm term = navigationTermSet.CreateTerm("Bing Search", NavigationLinkType.SimpleLink, Guid.NewGuid());
term.SimpleLinkUrl = "http://www.bing.com/";
// Creates new term pointing to an existing SharePoint page
NavigationTerm term2 = navigationTermSet.CreateTerm("Target page", NavigationLinkType.FriendlyUrl, Guid.NewGuid());
term2.TargetUrl.Value = "~site/Pages/TargetPage.aspx";
```

Hope this helps

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163978.aspx

Comment: Anuja, thank you for the comment but it did not help. My question is if I have term store setup and simply want to retrieve term properties especially friendly URL and simple link. I do not like to create new terms by using NavigationTerm.

Comment: Hell Anuja. Your comment did not answer my question but point to the right direction. I managed to retrieve those properties by using NavigationTermSet.

Comment: Glad that it helps to you

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (term in termSet.terms)
{
    string URL = term.LocalCustomProperties["_Sys_Nav_SimpleLinkUrl"];
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect

Comment: @EricHerlitz What is incorrect about this? The solution worked for me when I tried it.

Comment: This works fairly well!! And if I am not using NavigationTermSet this has to be used (for TermSet).

Comment: I am unable to get the value using term.LocalCustomProperties["_Sys_Nav_SimpleLinkUrl"];. My navigation url is properly set in sharepoint. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

The missing link is the bridge between TermSet and NavigationTermSet. As Anuja correctly stated, the responsible method is

```
NavigationTermSet.GetAsResolvedByWeb
```

So, here's my complete example - took me more than a day to figure it out (a different approach was working in an ASPX page but failed in the Web Service I was programming).

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy;
using System;

TaxonomySession taxonomySession = new TaxonomySession(site);
StandardNavigationSettings navigationSettings = new WebNavigationSettings(site.RootWeb).CurrentNavigation;
TermStore termStore = taxonomySession.TermStores[navigationSettings.TermStoreId];
TermSet termSet = termStore.GetTermSet(navigationSettings.TermSetId);
NavigationTermSet navigationTermSet = NavigationTermSet.GetAsResolvedByWeb(termSet, site.RootWeb, StandardNavigationProviderNames.GlobalNavigationTaxonomyProvider);

foreach (NavigationTerm navigationTerm in navigationTerms)
{
    Console.WriteLine("navigationTerm.GetResolvedDisplayUrl(string.Empty): " + navigationTerm.GetResolvedDisplayUrl(string.Empty));
}
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: I hope it helps too - sounds like something I'm trying to do, so I'm linking and I'll return when I get to that point. I'll upvote if it does help - thanks regardless!

Answer (score 0):

Use the code snippet below to get TermStore LocalCustomProperties.

```
TermCollection termCollection = termSet.GetAllTerms();
foreach (Term term in termCollection)
{
    string linkUrl = string.Empty;
    term.LocalCustomProperties.TryGetValue("_Sys_Nav_SimpleLinkUrl", out linkUrl);
}
```